# RETURN all the keypad subsequences

Tags: c++, string, recursion, cartesian-product

We have a phone keypad. Using it we have to find out all the possible strings thag can be made using digits of input n. We have to return the strings and not print it. For 0 and 1 return empty string. Have to use recursion.

For eg for 23 output will be :- ad ae af bd be bf cd ce cf

I tried alot to do this question but i am not to code. Please help

Comment: Do you succeed for single digit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I will do recursively call the create a string

```cpp
class Solution{
public:
   map<int,string> KeyMapping;
   void generate_string(string &current, vector<int> &keys, vector<string> &ans){
      if(current.size() == keys.size()){
          ans.emplace_back(current);
          return;
      }
      int index = (int)current.size();
      for(char i: keyMapping[keys[index]]){     
         current+=i;
         generate_string(current,keys,ans);
         current.pop_back();
      }      
   }
};
```

To use it in `main()`

```cpp
int main(){
  vector<int> keys = {1,2};
  string res = "";
  Solution obj;
  // Set keymapping to obj.keyMapping
  vector<string> all;
  obj.generate_string(res,keys,all);
  for(auto i: all)cout << i << " ";
  return 0;
}
```